# Where to add a p tag in line of code React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, variables, tags

I have two component where I am rendering images and links from a data js file. I would also like to generate a paragraph but am unsure where I can call the paragraph tag to generate it on both my ProjectList.js and Project.js components.
I'd like it to be just under the image.

Project.js

```
import "./project.css";

const Project = ({ img, link }) => {
  return (
    <div className="p">
      <div className="p-browser">
        <div className="p-circle">Tick</div>
        <div className="p-circle"></div>
        <div className="p-circle"></div>
      </div>
      <a href={link} target="_blank">
        <img src={img} alt="" className="p-img" />
        <p>kscjksnkdjs</p>
      </a>
      <div className="p-right">
        <div className="p-bg"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Project;
```

ProjectList.js

```
import "./projectList.css";
import Project from "../project/Project";
import { projects } from "../../data";

const ProjectList = () => {
  //   console.log(projects);
  return (
    <div className="pl">
      <div className="pl-texts">
        <h1 className="pl-title">Projects</h1>
        <p className="pl-description">
          {/* Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum sunt ad
          vitae. Quo maxime quos odit? Fuga omnis suscipit numquam adipisci unde
          aliquid vel deleniti ex eos excepturi. Atque, nostrum. */}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="pl-list">
        {projects.map((project) => (
          <Project key={project.id} img={project.img} link={project.link} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="text">thsisihsjihih</div>
      <div className="pl-right">
        <div className="pl-bg"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectList;
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "I would also like to generate a paragraph"? Do you mean dynamically generating a HTML element in React?

Comment: sorry if I'm not clear. See on ProjectList.js the mapped area:
 {projects.map((project) => (
          <Project key={project.id} img={project.img} link={project.link} />
        ))}

ideally I'd like a p tag there that will render a paragraph under each image.

Comment: Where should the content for the p tag come from? projects? @goatstash

Comment: import { projects } from "../../data"

I'm hoping to link it like this:
{ project.text }

the information is saved in an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Following your comments above.

In other to display each project's text in a `p` tag

**You should:**

1. Make the `Project` component accept another prop value called `text` similar to `img` and `link`
2. Use interpolation ({}) to display it within the `p` in the `Project` component
3. Then pass each project's `text` into the `Project` component in the `map`

**Checkout the code example below**

```js
// Project component
const Project = ({ img, link, text }) => {
  return (
    <div className="p">

      ...rest of the code block
    
      <a href={link} target="_blank">
        <img src={img} alt="" className="p-img" />
        <p>{text}</p>
      </a>

      ...rest of the code block

    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
// ProjectList
...rest of the code block

{projects.map((project) => ( 
  <Project key={project.id} img={project.img} link={project.link} text={project.text}/>
))}

...rest of the code block
```

Also, if you wish to display a project's text in the `p` tag within your `ProjectList` component then you must pick one project from the list of projects.

You can pick and display the first project in the list using the zero index like this

```js
// ProjectList
const ProjectList = () => {
  //   console.log(projects);
  return (
    <div className="pl">
      <div className="pl-texts">

       ...rest of the code block

        <p className="pl-description">
          {projects[0].text}
        </p>

       ...rest of the code block

      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```